# remove `\"` from string rails 4

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4

I have params like:

```
params[:id]= "\"ebfd11a9-3aa4-415a-ba72-1b6796ea1bf6\""
```

And i want to get expected result as below:

```
"ebfd11a9-3aa4-415a-ba72-1b6796ea1bf6"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where does that data come from, i.e. who is making the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```
"\"ebfd11a9-3aa4-415a-ba72-1b6796ea1bf6\"".gsub("\"", "")
=> "ebfd11a9-3aa4-415a-ba72-1b6796ea1bf6"
```

Or, as @Stefan mentioned, `delete`:

```
"\"ebfd11a9-3aa4-415a-ba72-1b6796ea1bf6\"".delete("\"")
=> "ebfd11a9-3aa4-415a-ba72-1b6796ea1bf6"
```

Comment: You can also use `delete` to remove single characters, it has less overhead than `gsub`.

Answer (score 4):

If this is JSON data, which it could very well be in that format:

```
JSON.load(params[:id])
```

This handles things where there's somehow escaped strings in there, or the parameters are an array.

Comment: Rails should parse JSON data automatically.

Comment: It can only do this via POST. If this comes in via GET it won't go through the same handlers, and it's pretty easy to make an AJAX call with incorrectly serialized query parameters.

Comment: `JSON.load(params[:id])` would help in that specific case, but it would result in a parse error if the data comes in correctly.

Comment: @Stefan If it came in correctly this question wouldn't be on Stack Overflow. This handles more exotic cases better but doesn't degrade. The others degrade, but mangle more complicated params. It's a coin-toss as to which is better. You're right, but I'm not sure you're right in the right way.

Comment: I don't think that the others handle it any better (blindly removing characters can easily corrupt data). I just think that you should not tailor an API to handle invalid requests or data.

Answer (score 1):

**Just Use tr!**

```
params[:id].tr!("\"","")
```

tr! will also change the main string

In case you do not want to change main string just use :

```
params[:id].tr("\"","")
```

**Thanks Ilya**

Comment: better use `tr` without exclamation mark except cases if you want modify source string